# Have 2 blocking scripts interact with each other in linux

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, shell, ffmpeg

I have 2 blocking shell scripts which I want to have interact with each other. The scripts in question are peerflix (nodejs script) and ffmpeg (a simple bash script).

What happens: Peerflix fires up, feeds data to ffmpeg bash scrip which terminates peerflix on completion.

So once peerflix starts it outputs 2 lines and blocks immediately:

```
[08:15 PM]-[vagrant@packer-virtualbox-iso]-[/var/www/test]-[git master] 
$ node /var/www/test/node/node_modules/peerflix/app.js /var/www/test/flexget/torrents/test.torrent -r -q
listening: http://10.0.2.15:38339/
process: 9601
```

I have to feed the listening address to the ffmpeg bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00 -i {THE_LISTENING_PORT} -frames:v 1 out1.jpg
ffmpeg -ss 00:10:00 -i {THE_LISTENING_PORT} -frames:v 1 out2.jpg
```

After the bash script is done I have to kill the peerflix script (hence me outputting the PID).

My question is how do I achieve this?

Comment: basically same question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168737/4667

Comment: @glennjackman not really, this one is broader, geared more towards how to build up the code. The other one is very specific

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
# Start the node process in the background
node /var/www/test/node/node_modules/peerflix/app.js /var/www/test/flexget/torrents/test.torrent -r -q &
# Get the PID of the node process
PID=$!

# Run your stuff    
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00 -i {THE_LISTENING_PORT} -frames:v 1 out1.jpg
ffmpeg -ss 00:10:00 -i {THE_LISTENING_PORT} -frames:v 1 out2.jpg

# Stop the node process
kill $PID
```

You could put this in one script or have a node script that starts/kills the node process be a wrapper and run another script in the middle. Hope this helps.